# T-SQL (transact-SQL) valid in SQLite and other SQL databases?

Tags: mysql, sql, t-sql, sqlite

There doesn't seem to be any clear info out there about T-SQL and the ability to use it in SQLite and other non-microsoft SQL implementations. Most articles I come across say its Microsoft proprietary, so can we use T-SQL statements like CASE etc. on a SQLite database?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

T-SQL is Microsoft's implementation (dialect) of the ANSI SQL standard.  Like most implementations, there are *portions* that are proprietary and not standard, quirks that are permissible but not idiomatic for other platforms, and items defined in the standard that are not implemented.  MySQL, sqlite, and others are the same way, and so sometimes a quirk with another platform will make "correct" and standards-compliant T-SQL be broken for that platform.

In other words, if you know T-SQL, you know about 85% of what you need to write queries for SQLite, MySQL, oracle, db2, Informix, Access, etc.  However, there will be a few bumps; definitely don't expect code written for one platform to work on another.

`CASE` is one of those instances where the various flavors of sql tend to differ, with a number of other implementations choosing a syntax based on `IF` instead.  The core `SELECT`, `FROM`, `WHERE` keywords, on the other hand, tend to be more consistent.

Comment: TransactSQL (T-SQL) was Sybase's extension of the SQL language before Microsoft copied it, and it remains the closest thing to MSSQL Server syntax (though differences have evolved).

Comment: In addition to what hardmath said, ANSI is intended to consolidate the differences between various vendor implementations but that does not mean the entire spec is implemented, or that the functionality performs as well as pre-existing native syntax.

Comment: @hardmath just to be clear, Microsoft didn't "*copy*" T-SQL from Sybase, they *bought* it. Just don't want any false perceptions out there, as "copied" code tends to imply "stolen." http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server

Answer (score 8):

ANSI [SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL) is the standard Structured Query Language.

Most database vendors support SQL. [T-SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transact-SQL) is Microsoft's version of ANSI SQL.